# Correct way of updating an actor with changes applied to SetUserTransform

Tags: vtk

I have a poly actor which has a vtkBoxWidget that is connected to a callback as from the example in the docs:

```
def widget_callback(obj, event):
    t = vtk.vtkTransform()
    obj.GetTransform(t)
    obj.GetProp3D().SetUserTransform(t)
```

All works fine and I am able to move and transform the actor with the widget but the transformation is applied to the UserTransform and not processed down to the actor properties.

So if I call:

```
actor.GetPosition()
```

It returns the initial position prior to making the changes with the widget. And if I call:

```
actor.GetUserTransform().GetPosition()
```

I get the updated position relative to the starting point of the first interaction.

Do I have to connect it all through a vtkTransformPolyDataFilter and then update the input connection to the mapper and also calculate the coordinate space offset or is there a simpler way of doing it? ... in short:

**What is the correct way of updating an actor with changes applied to SetUserTransform?**

Answer (score 1):

After trying out many variations with vtkTransformPolyDataFilter and start/end interaction events linked to various steps in the process I found that for my purpose the absolute simplest way of handling this was simply linking the widget transformation directly to the actor properties:

```
    def widget_callback(self, obj, event):
        t = vtk.vtkTransform()
        obj.GetTransform(t)

        self.actor.SetPosition(t.GetPosition())
        self.actor.SetScale(t.GetScale())
        self.actor.SetOrientation(t.GetOrientation())
```